Can Graph Neural Networks Produce Accurate Embeddings with Only Node Attributes at Inference Time?
I am training a Graph Neural Network (GNN) using graph structural features and node embeddings during training to generate embeddings for nodes in a graph. However, at inference time, I only have access to node attributes without the graph connectivity information. My concern is whether the GNN can still produce meaningful and accurate embeddings based solely on these node attributes.
During training, the GNN learns from both the graph structure and node features to generate embeddings. But in my real-world scenario, obtaining the full graph structure might not always be feasible or practical.
I'm wondering if the GNN, which has been trained on graph structural and node embeddings, can still provide valuable embeddings when only given node attributes during inference. Has anyone encountered a similar situation or has insights into the effectiveness of GNNs in such scenarios? Any suggestions or experiences would be greatly appreciated.
